# Battleship game in python

Tags: python

I am creating a battleship game in python. I have created a board that is 10X10 and looks as such.

```
-------------------------------------------------
 1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 | 10 | 
-------------------------------------------------
11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 
-------------------------------------------------
21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 
-------------------------------------------------
31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35 | 36 | 37 | 38 | 39 | 40 | 
-------------------------------------------------
41 | 42 | 43 | 44 | 45 | 46 | 47 | 48 | 49 | 50 | 
-------------------------------------------------
51 | 52 | 53 | 54 | 55 | 56 | 57 | 58 | 59 | 60 | 
-------------------------------------------------
61 | 62 | 63 | 64 | 65 | 66 | 67 | 68 | 69 | 70 | 
-------------------------------------------------
71 | 72 | 73 | 74 | 75 | 76 | 77 | 78 | 79 | 80 | 
-------------------------------------------------
81 | 82 | 83 | 84 | 85 | 86 | 87 | 88 | 89 | 90 | 
-------------------------------------------------
91 | 92 | 93 | 94 | 95 | 96 | 97 | 98 | 99 | 100| 
-------------------------------------------------
```

Now I have a list of where the ships are located as such:
    s = [[21,22,23,24,25],
        [45,55,65,75],
        [1,2,3],
        [85,86,87],
        [5,15],
        [46,56]]

I am trying to write a function that allows input from the user for a spot, if the input is in the list s, it should return hit. if not it will return miss.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def createBoard():
    board=[]
    for i in range(10):
        board.append(str(i)+" ")
    for j in range(10,100):
        board.append(j)
    return(board)
def printBoard(board):
    for i in range(0,100,10):
        print("\n"+"-"*45)
        for j in range(1,10,1):
            print(board[i+j],"|",end=" ")
    print("\n"+"-"*45)
printBoard(createBoard())

position=int(input("Choose position on the board"))
g="Miss"
a="hit"
s = [[21,22,23,24,25],
    [45,55,65,75],
    [1,2,3],
    [85,86,87],
    [5,15],
    [46,56]]
for i in range(0,len(s),1):
    if position in s[i]:
        print(a)
    elif position not in s[i]:
        print(g)
```

So far it finds whether or not the input is in the list but it returns it five times and I only want it to be returned once. I can only use basic code because I do not know much advanced work.

Comment: It would make it significantly easier to use a 2D list, rather than that funky list you have going on at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a break statement after your `print(a)`.  This will exit (break out of) the for loop.

**EDIT:**

As it stands, if you miss it will print it out 5 times too.  You need to set some variable before your loop and only after you have checked all the ships, if you have not found one then print it out (only once, outside the loop)

```
    found = False
    for i in range(0,len(s),1):
        if position in s[i]:
            print(a)
            found = True
            break
    if not found:
        print(g)
```

Comment: This will print "Miss" for each sublist that does not contain `position`.

Comment: My answer's basically word for word the same now, so +1! :)

Answer (score 0):

There you go. You can use the `any` function. It will return true if one ship gets hit. Although, as already mentioned, for a more advanced version of the game I also recommend using a 2d array

```
def print_board():
    def print_separator():
        print("-"*51)

    for i in range(0, 100, 10):
        print_separator()
        field_string = " | ".join(['{:2d}'.format(i+j) for j in range(0, 10)])
        print(f'| {field_string} |')
    print_separator()

print_board()

ships = [[21,22,23,24,25],
    [45,55,65,75],
    [1,2,3],
    [85,86,87],
    [5,15],
    [46,56]]

def is_hit(position):
    return any([position in ship_location for ship_location in ships])

def evaluate_position(position):
    print("hit" if is_hit(position) else "Miss")

while 1:
    pos = input("Choose position on the board: ")
    if(pos == "exit"):
        exit()
    
    evaluate_position(int(pos))
```